# Display List of data when button is clicked

Tags: arrays, json, swift, api

I have 2 different JSON and I want to display list of data when the image from the collectionview is pressed to my another view controller.

Those list of data should be clickable also.

It would be one SkillsName(`TSCSkillName`) to many Training's (`TSCTtopicName`)

SAMPLE JSON

```
 {
    "TSCskillID": 1,
    "TSCProficiency": "Product",
    "TSCLevel": "Fundamental",
    "TSCSkillName": "Product Usability",
    "TSCskillLOGO": "images\/TSCskillLogo\/Product Usability.jpg",
    "TSCskillDescription": "SKILLS Test Description"
 }
```

For the second JSON

```
  {
    "TSCProficiency": "Product",
    "TSCSkillName": "Product Usability",
    "TSCskillDescription": "SKILLS Test Description",
    "TSCLevel": "Fundamental",
    "TSCskillLOGO": "images\/TSCskillLogo\/Product Usability.jpg",
    "TSCTtopicID": 1,
    "TSCTtopicName": "Trend Micro Security",
    "TSCTtopicDescription": "TOPIC Test Description",
    "Status": "Done",
    "TSCTMemorabilia": "images\/Memorabilia"   
  },
  {
    "TSCProficiency": "Product",
    "TSCSkillName": "Product Usability",
    "TSCskillDescription": "SKILLS Test Description",
    "TSCLevel": "Fundamental",
    "TSCskillLOGO": "images\/TSCskillLogo\/Product Usability.jpg",
    "TSCTtopicID": 2,
    "TSCTtopicName": "Trend Micro Antivirus for Mac",
    "TSCTtopicDescription": "TOPIC Test Description",
    "Status": "Done",
    "TSCTMemorabilia": "images\/Memorabilia"  
  }
```

```
// I used this data to display the images to my collectionview

struct getSkills: Codable {
    let TSCProficiency, TSCSkillName, TSCskillDescription, TSCLevel: String
    let TSCskillLOGO: String
    let TSCTtopicID: Int?
    let TSCTtopicName, TSCTtopicDescription, status, TSCTMemorabilia: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case TSCProficiency = "TSCProficiency"
        case TSCSkillName = "TSCSkillName"
        case TSCskillDescription = "TSCskillDescription"
        case TSCLevel = "TSCLevel"
        case TSCskillLOGO = "TSCskillLOGO"
        case TSCTtopicID = "TSCTtopicID"
        case TSCTtopicName = "TSCTtopicName"
        case TSCTtopicDescription = "TSCTtopicDescription"
        case status = "Status"
        case TSCTMemorabilia = "TSCTMemorabilia"
    }
}

struct skills {
    static var TSCskillLOGO : String = "Photo Location"
    static var TSCskillID: String = "1"
    static var TSCProficiency: String = "Skill Proficiency"
    static var TSCSkillName: String = "Skill Name"
    static var TSCskillDescription: String = "Skill Description"
    static var TSCLevel: String = "Skill Level"
    static var TSCTtopicID: String = "Trainings ID"
    static var TSCTtopicName: String = "Training Name"
    static var TSCTtopicDescription: String = "Training Description"
    static var Status: String = "Status"
    static var TSCTMemorabilia: String = "Memorabilia"
}

struct testSkills: Codable {
    let TSCskillID: Int
    let TSCProficiency, TSCLevel,TSCSkillName, TSCskillLOGO: String
    let TSCskillDescription: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case TSCskillID = "TSCskillID"
        case TSCProficiency = "TSCProficiency"
        case TSCLevel = "TSCLevel"
        case TSCSkillName = "TSCSkillName"
        case TSCskillLOGO = "TSCskillLOGO"
        case TSCskillDescription = "TSCskillDescription"
    }
}

class SkillsTreeViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var skillsCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var skillsCatLbl: UILabel!

 var getSkillsInfo = [getSkills]()
    var testSkillsInfo = [testSkills]()
    var badges: [UIImage] = []
    var isBadgeLoaded = false
    var retryTimes = 0


// You may check my code below

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        skillsCollectionView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        skillsCollectionView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        skillsCatLbl.text = "Network"

        loadData()
    }

    func loadData() {
        handleCollectionViewLayout(collectionView: skillsCollectionView)
        getTestSkillsList {
            self.addValuesToVariables {
                self.handleLoading(view: self.skillsCollectionView, isDoneLoading: !self.isBadgeLoaded)
                self.loadImages()
            }
        }
        //        getSkillsDetails {}
    }
  func addValuesToVariables(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {

        skills.TSCskillLOGO = testSkillsInfo[0].TSCskillLOGO
        skills.TSCProficiency = testSkillsInfo[0].TSCProficiency
        skills.TSCSkillName = testSkillsInfo[0].TSCSkillName
       skills.TSCskillDescription = testSkillsInfo[0].TSCskillDescription
        skills.TSCLevel = testSkillsInfo[0].TSCLevel
       skills.TSCskillID = String(testSkillsInfo[0].TSCskillID)

            completed()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       // return getSkillsInfo.count
        return testSkillsInfo.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let collectionviewcell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionviewcell", for: indexPath) as! FAMECell

        collectionviewcell.skillsBadgePic?.addImageShadow(shadowOffset: CGSize(width: 0, height: 0), shadowColor: UIColor.black.cgColor, shadowRadius: 0.5, shadowOpacity: 5.0)
        collectionviewcell.skillsBadgePic?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        if isBadgeLoaded {
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
          collectionviewcell.skillsBadgePic?.image = badges[indexPath.item]
        }
        return collectionviewcell
        //collectionviewcell.skillsBadgePic?.image = getSkillsInfo[indexPath.item].image
        //}
    //    print(getSkillsInfo[indexPath.item].image!)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("User Tapped: \(indexPath.item)")

        let selectedCell = skillsCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! FAMECell
        let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard (name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let desVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SkillsTreePopUpViewController") as! SkillsTreePopUpViewController

        desVC.badgeTitle = testSkillsInfo[indexPath.item].TSCSkillName
        desVC.badgeImage = selectedCell.skillsBadgePic?.image
        desVC.badgeDescription = testSkillsInfo[indexPath.item].TSCskillDescription
        desVC.skillID = testSkillsInfo[indexPath.item].TSCskillID
        desVC.trainingsBtn = getSkillsInfo[indexPath.item].TSCTtopicName //getting an error on this line [array is nil]

        self.present(desVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

func getTestSkillsList(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {

        let fcat = self.skillsCatLbl.text

        let siebelid = engineerProfileInfo.siebelID
        let rootLink = "https://skills.dasq.com/iOS/testskills.php?"
        let url = URL (string: rootLink + "id=" + siebelid + "&fcat=" + fcat!)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {(data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                do {
                    self.testSkillsInfo = try JSONDecoder().decode([testSkills].self, from: data!)
                    print(self.testSkillsInfo)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completed()
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("JSON Error: Skills Tree")
                    self.handleJSONErrorAlert()
                }
            } else {
                self.handleNoNetAlert()
            }
            }.resume()
    }

    func getSkillsDetails(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {

        let tid = skills.TSCskillID
        let siebelid = engineerProfileInfo.siebelID
        let rootLink = "https://skills.dasq.com/iOS/getskillspage.php"
       let url = URL (string: rootLink + "sid=" + siebelid + "&tid=" + tid )

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {(data, response, error) in
            if error == nil { // getting an error here that array is nil
                do { 
                    self.getSkillsInfo = try JSONDecoder().decode([getSkills].self, from: data!)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completed()
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("JSON Error: Trainings Details")
                    print (error)
                    self.handleJSONErrorAlert()
                }
            } else {
                self.handleNoNetAlert()
            }
            }.resume()
    }

    func loadImages(){
        for index in 1...testSkillsInfo.count {
            let badgeTitle = testSkillsInfo[index-1].TSCSkillName
            let completeLink = "https://skills.dasq.com/" + "images/TSCskillLogo/\(badgeTitle).jpg"
        let imageUrlString = completeLink.addingPercentEncoding( withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
        let url = URL(string: imageUrlString!)
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
        let coloredPic = UIImage(data: data!)

        badges.append(coloredPic!)
        }
            isBadgeLoaded = !isBadgeLoaded
            print(badges.count)
         self.skillsCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: Please explain what you tried and what did not work. Did you get any errors in your implementation?

Comment: @Anand got an error on this ' desVC.trainingsBtn = getSkillsInfo[indexPath.item].TSCTtopicName ' -- > Cannot be called with asCopy = NO on non-main thread.

Comment: I missed your error embedded in your code. It clearly states that your JSON is invalid. Let me post the correct decodable struct

Comment: got an error on this part dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.})))

Answer (score 0):

Please check you decodable struct. I have generated one for you. The error shows that

> JSON text did not start with array.

So, try to decode "TopicName" which is an array of "TopicNameElement"

**SkillName**

```
struct SkillName: Codable {
    let tsCskillID: Int
    let tscProficiency, tscLevel, tscSkillName, tsCskillLOGO: String
    let tsCskillDescription: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case tsCskillID = "TSCskillID"
        case tscProficiency = "TSCProficiency"
        case tscLevel = "TSCLevel"
        case tscSkillName = "TSCSkillName"
        case tsCskillLOGO = "TSCskillLOGO"
        case tsCskillDescription = "TSCskillDescription"
    }
}
```

**TopicName**

```
typealias TopicName = [TopicNameElement]

struct TopicNameElement: Codable {
    let tscProficiency, tscSkillName, tsCskillDescription, tscLevel: String
    let tsCskillLOGO: String
    let tscTtopicID: Int
    let tscTtopicName, tscTtopicDescription, status, tsctMemorabilia: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case tscProficiency = "TSCProficiency"
        case tscSkillName = "TSCSkillName"
        case tsCskillDescription = "TSCskillDescription"
        case tscLevel = "TSCLevel"
        case tsCskillLOGO = "TSCskillLOGO"
        case tscTtopicID = "TSCTtopicID"
        case tscTtopicName = "TSCTtopicName"
        case tscTtopicDescription = "TSCTtopicDescription"
        case status = "Status"
        case tsctMemorabilia = "TSCTMemorabilia"
    }
}
```

Comment: got an error on the same line -- > ype 'getSkillsInfo' (aka 'Array<getSkills>') has no member 'TSCTtopicName'

Comment: you should access the member as present in decodable struct. There is no member as "TSCTtopicName". It is actually "tscTtopicName" in TopicNameElement which is an element in TopicName array.

Comment: now it says on the same line - > Fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: It means array element is not accessed properly. If the number of elements in the array is 5 and if we try to access 6 element, we get this error. Please check in that aspect.

Comment: If I put the desVC.trainingsBtn = getSkillsInfo[indexPath.item].TSCTtopicName will it automatically get all of the TSCTtopicName (from the different JSON) for the TSCskillName that was selected on the collectionview?

Comment: if getSkillsInfo returns TSCTtopicName array, then TopicNameElement can be accessed by passing the correct index. Once it is accessed, topicName can be accessed as TopicNameElement.tscTtopicName. So it will be like "getSkillsInfo[indexPath.item].tscTtopicName"

Comment: yes already used that but keeps on saying that the array for TopicNameElement is nil

Comment: Can you update the question with "getSkillsInfo" code, JSON value and decoding code?

Comment: getSkillsInfo and testSkillsInfo array are initialized with empty array. Can you show how the values are populated into that from JSON?